# PHP hosting and URL display

Tags: php, mysql, url, redirect, dns

I have a site using PHP and MySQL. I have a domain name reserved by a domain name provider. I do not want to use the storage proposed by that provider to store my files, because it's really too expensive.

Let's say the domain name is : `www.domainname.com`

So... If I choose another provider (let's imagine it's free.fr) to store my site's files, **what may I do, or what may I look for, to be able to have in my url bar** :

```
http://www.domainname.com/onefolder/onegreatfile.php
```

instead of :

```
http://imhere.free.fr/innerfreefrfolder/onefolder/onegreatfile.php
```

If I activate the transparent redirection on my domain name, the url keeps being :

```
http://www.domainname.com
```

If I force the url bar to go to `http://www.domainname.com/onefolder/onegreatfile.php`

it returns a `404 not found error (The requested URL /onefolder/onegreatfile.php was not found on this server.)`

Answer (score 0):

The following is an oversimplification but it should be enough to get you where you need to go:

You'll want to sign up with a web host that allows you to use your domain name with their server. They will tell you what to set your name servers to so that any requests for `www.domainname.com` will result in the ip address of the server your files are stored on. Setting the name servers for your domain is usually done via a service provided by your registrar.

Comment: Will this work if my files are stored on a subfolder on a server, like into http://imhere.free.fr/innerfreefrfolder/ ?

Comment: Yes, it will work. Once you sign up with the web host, you can upload your files into any folders that you wish and they will be accessed like `http://www.domainname.com/onefolder/onegreatfile.php`

Comment: I've found the DNS configutaion options. What may I change to make "www.mydomain.com" display what is stored at "somedomain.free.fr/mydomain/" and continue displaying in the url bar www.mydomain.com ?

Comment: You need to ask the folks at `free.fr` It may be that they don't support it which is why my answer states `You'll want to sign up with a web host that allows you to use your domain name with their server`

Answer (score 0):

The transparent redirection you're referring to (some hosting sites call it Forwarding with Masking) is really just your hosted files displaying within an iframe on your owned domain name.

What you really need to look into is setting the **DNS servers/Nameservers** for your domain name to point to your hosted website/IP address.

Comment: Will this work if my files are stored on a subfolder on a server, like into http://imhere.free.fr/innerfreefrfolder/ ?